# How to configure visual studio code java.home for both windows and wsl

Tags: visual-studio-code

Question about VS Code. If I launch code from Windows, settings.json needs a windows path to java.home. If I launch from Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), settings.json needs a linux path. But VSC uses the same settings.json whether launched for windows or wsl, so I'm always broken on one or the other. There must be a way around this.

If you have a .vscode directory in your project, you can drop a settings.json in there and VS code will pick it up. But that is less than optimal.

The --user-data-dir option does not work from WSL. `code --help` doesn't even show it as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

In settings.json, make sure "java.home" is not set, i.e., "java.home" : "", and VSC will pick it up from JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME (in that order).